# Insert if not exists doesn't work. I have 20000 records in JSON file. I want to do insert/update into table from json table accordingly using SP

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, bulkinsert, bulkupdate

I want to update/insert records from Json table ( which has 5000 records) to another table .
when I run for first time Insert works fine and when I update ,it updates accordingly.
But when I ran again the same file with additional records it doesn't insert the records.
can someone help me with this ?
Below is my code

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[load_consultation_data] 
   
    @consultation_json NVARCHAR(MAX)

    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
AS  
    BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

   DECLARE @JSON VARCHAR(MAX)
  SET @JSON = @consultation_json
    
    DECLARE @jsontable table 
                             (
                               customerID NVARCHAR(50),
                               clinicID NVARCHAR(50),
                               birdId NVARCHAR(80),                 
                               consultationId NVARCHAR(80),  
                               employeeName NVARCHAR(150),
                               totalPrice MONEY,               
                               row_num int
                              ) 

/* Importing nested Json data */
      INSERT INTO @jsontable  
      SELECT customer.customerID             AS  customerID
             ,customer.clinicID          AS  clinicID 
             ,consultation.birdId            AS  birdId 
             ,consultation.consultationId    AS  consultationId         
             ,consultation.employeeName      AS  employeeName            
             ,consultation.totalPrice         AS  totalPrice               
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY consultationId ) row_num            
             FROM OPENJSON (@JSON, '$')
             WITH (customerID VARCHAR(50) '$.customerID',
             clinicID VARCHAR(50) '$.clinic.clinicID') as customer

             CROSS APPLY openjson(@json,'$.clinic.consultation')
             WITH(
             birdId NVARCHAR(80),
             consultationId NVARCHAR(80),                                   
             employeeName NVARCHAR(150),     
             totalPrice MONEY           
            ) as consultation       
        INNER JOIN dbo.clinic AS clinic_tab ON clinic_tab.external_id = customer.clinicID
            INNER JOIN dbo.bird AS bird_tab ON bird_tab.external_bird_id = consultation.birdId



                    /** If consultation record doesn't exists then do insert else update **/
    IF NOT EXISTS 
       (
       SELECT  1
       FROM dbo.consultation AS con
       INNER JOIN dbo.bird AS al ON con.external_bird_id = al.external_bird_id AND al.clinic_id = con.clinic_id
       INNER JOIN dbo.clinic AS pr ON con.clinic_id = pr.id
       INNER JOIN @jsontable AS rjson ON rjson.consultationId = con.external_consultation_id
       WHERE con.external_consultation_id = rjson.consultationId 
       AND pr.external_id = rjson.clinicID 
       AND al.external_bird_id = rjson.birdId )


BEGIN
                   /** Insert recored into consultation table **/

    INSERT INTO dbo.[consultation]                            
                      (
            [external_consultation_id]   
                       ,[external_bird_id]         
                       ,[clinic_id]                    
                       ,[bird_id]        
                       ,[employee_name]       
                       ,[total_price]     
            
                        )  

      SELECT   rjson.consultationId        AS    [external_consultation_id]   
                        ,rjson.[birdId]       AS    [external_bird_id]         
                        ,bird_tab.clinic_id AS    [clinic_id]                    
                        ,bird_tab.[id]        AS    [bird_id]    
                        ,rjson.employeeName     AS    [employee_name] 
                        ,rjson.totalPrice       AS    [total_price]   
                        FROM @jsontable as rjson                        
                        INNER JOIN dbo.bird AS bird_tab on bird_tab.external_bird_id = rjson.birdId 
                        INNER JOIN  dbo.clinic AS clinic_tab on clinic_tab.external_id = rjson.clinicID 
                        WHERE rjson.consultationId = rjson.consultationId --@consultationID
                        and bird_tab.clinic_id = clinic_tab.id 


END 

ELSE

BEGIN
                       /* Update Records into consultation table */

    UPDATE  dbo.[consultation] SET    
    [external_bird_id]      =  rjson.[birdId]     
    ,[clinic_id]                  =  al.clinic_id      
    ,[bird_id]                  =  al.[id]        
    ,[employee_name]              =  rjson.employeeName    
    ,[total_price]                =  rjson.totalPrice 
     FROM dbo.consultation AS con
     INNER JOIN dbo.bird AS al ON con.external_bird_id = al.external_bird_id AND al.clinic_id = con.clinic_id
     INNER JOIN dbo.clinic AS pr ON con.clinic_id = pr.id
     INNER JOIN @jsontable AS rjson ON rjson.consultationId = con.external_consultation_id
     WHERE con.external_consultation_id = rjson.consultationId 
     AND pr.external_id = rjson.clinicID 
     AND al.external_bird_id = rjson.birdId 


     END 
     END
```

Comment: Without the JSON and the table definitions, how can we possibly help? It looks strange that you are doing `CROSS APPLY openjson(@json,'$.clinic.consultation')` I would have expected `CROSS APPLY openjson(customer.clinic, '$.consultation')`. Also `IF NOT EXISTS` is only going to work if there is a single row

Comment: I tried using while loop and insert /update row one by one. It works fine but it takes 4 min to execute. So ,I removed the loop and tried the above code. First run, inserts all records perfectly well, but when I add few more records to json it doesn't insert records. Any other alternative for me so that the stored procedure updates/insert records  in less than 30 seconds for 20000 records in json table .

Comment: We need at least a sample JSON, perhaps a couple of records. We also need the table definitions, and a better description of what you are trying to achieve (in terms of matching/`not exists`)